# How do we "freeze" the display on an external display?

Tags: windows, laptop, external-display

I currently have an external display connected to my laptop.

How can we temporarily "freeze" the screen of the external display, such that we can continue using the laptop without having the screen of external display changing?

I'm running Windows on an [Acer Aspire 4937G](http://asia.cnet.com/product/acer-aspire-4937g-core-2-duo-t9550-processor-266ghz-4gb-ram-44781126.htm)

Comment: What about a program that makes a screen-shot and then opens it? Would that be a "freeze" as you want it?

Comment: Are there any news on this topic? Perhaps with Win7 oder 8.1?

Comment: @Robert, that wouldn't work. I want to be able to continue using the laptop normally, but with the external display not reflecting the display on the laptop.

Comment: 3 answers and all are suggesting to extend the display, don't you know the word "freeze", @Pacerier have you got any solution for this?

Comment: Any development on this? @Pacerier. I use the extended display but there still come a time that I need to freeze the screen; much like I would, if the freeze button on my projector's remote was working. There has to be a way to freeze the second display from the PC.

Answer (score 2):

Use extend mode, and drag the window which you wish to freeze to the side of your laptop screen. This should display on the extended screen.

Comment: Isn't this the same as Bill's answer?

Answer (score 2):

In Windows one of the solution is using external display (as stated by each answer) but with some app for cloning/freezing, like [ComroeStudios DisplayClone](http://www.comroestudios.com/DisplayClone/Doc/DisplayClone.html) (it's available for free now) or [UltraMon](https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/download.asp).
Is is also possible to write your own app using GDI32 functions (PrintWindow, CreateCompatibleBitmap, ... and so on)

Answer (score 1):

Use the extend mode instead of the clone mode.

Then, put whatever you want to display on the external monitor, and continue using the laptop monitor

Comment: i mean i know about the extend mode, but it's abit different. what I want is like a program where i can like have 1 button which says "freeze" display on external display. then "unfreeze" and so on.

Answer (score 1):

click and hold fn, then F7. This will bring up the 4 options, click on the extend option. This will feed you projector a loop of what was on your screen when you pressed these buttons. To take it off of this, just press F7 again and select a different option, The small pictures pretty much explain everything.

Comment: Isn't this the same as Akash's answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can buy a remote for the item you are using for the external display and hit the freeze button on it. Hope you can get it

Comment: This is actually a good suggestion if the display supports it. For my TV you need to be in timeshift mode to do it, many beamers have it out of the box.